# JavaScript works in live environment but not on jsFiddle.net

Tags: javascript

This works in my "live" system but not when I paste it into Jsfiddle.
The function is just not being called when I change the select. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/uEQg2/1/

```
function InsertPrice(Variante) {
document.getElementById('pricebox-right').innerHTML = 'US $ ' + Variante;
return true; }
```

Comment: It looks like JSFiddle isn't loading the function correctly - it's throwing a "Uncaught ReferenceError: InsertPrice is not defined". Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uEQg2/2/

Comment: Try like this in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/uEQg2/4/

Comment: If you select the option "No Wrap - In body" then it will works.

Comment: @Dineshkani: Obviously not.

Comment: Yes, it works with the no wrap option. Thank you. The answers in the cross reference from Bergi where helpful too.